# Nothing happens on button click

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I'm fairly new to Cordova, and I'm trying to create a quick app that uses the device-motion plugin (accelerometer). I created a button in the index.html file which is supposed to make the X, Y, Z stuff pop up in an alert box, but the button does not appear to be doing anything.

Javascript stuff:

```
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    document.getElementById("btnClick").addEventListener("click", clickbtn);
},

function clickbtn(){    
      alert('Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '\n' +
      'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '\n' +
      'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '\n' +
      'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '\n');
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <button class="ui-btn" id="btnClick" >Get location</button> <br/>
</div>
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? (Alternatively, is there a way I can see what happens when the button gets pressed?)

Comment: `document.getElementById("btnClick")` are you sure the DOM is ready at this point?

Comment: please write down event listener and it's function in **receivedEvent:**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Your button will start working once phonegap is fully loaded.
Javascript code:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady(){
  document.getElementById("btnClick").onclick = function(){
     alert('Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '\n' +
      'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '\n' +
      'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '\n' +
      'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '\n');
 }
}
```

and Your HTML will remain same.

```
<div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <button class="ui-btn" id="btnClick" >Get location</button> <br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html

Your Body should call the onload-function:

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
```

The function onload should call the deviceready-function:

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
```

And you should create a deviceready-callback with the button-listener:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    $("#btnClick").click(function(){
       //make some funny things
       alert("clicked");
    });
}
```